# Server 2008 IIS 7.5 SSL Session Problem

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, https, session-state

I developed a e-commerce project. My project copies running on Server 2003 / IIS 6 with .Net Framework 4.0 .
Today, i have Server 2008 and IIS 7.5. Project is running normally but when i redirected https page, session is broken.

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

IIS creates different application pools for each http and https bindings. so session state will be different in each binding (protocol) so you can not access session from one protocol in other one, unless you set cookie in client machine or set cookie name for your session.

the simple solution is to set domain wide cookie in http page and retrieve it in https page!

Comment: I'm using session state with cookieless mode but problem is still going on :(

Comment: Are you kidding me ? You need to use cookies to correct this problem. don't disable cookies or do not use session state in cookieless mode. you should set domain wide cookies for your session to pass this error.

Comment: but this project running normally other 2008 servers.